# How to handle an adapter row clicks in MVVM pattern and data binding?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

In my recyclerview adapter cell layout, I'm passing the presenter as a binding and calling

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> mainPresenter.showDetail(booksItem)}"
```

from my layout XML to trigger showDetails method in a presenter.

But I've been told the presenter should not be passed in Databinding. Is there a valid reason for not passing the presenter and what would be the alternative to binding click actions on row cells.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="mainPresenter"
            type="com.noisyninja.androidlistpoc.views.main.IMainPresenter" />

        <variable
            name="booksItem"
            type="com.noisyninja.androidlistpoc.model.skoobe.BooksItem" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> mainPresenter.showDetail(booksItem)}"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_margin">
```

Comment: I think you have to pass the object of activity or fragment to your XML and it will provide you callback on your activity or fragment. from activity or fragment you have to call a method of presenter.

Comment: Can you please share link where you have been told not to pass presenter in binding?